# Spring JDBC and keeping objects and database in correct state

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-jdbc

I am creating an application in Spring JDBC and I have some questions regarding how to keep the object graphs and the database in correct state. If you have a car object with a list of parts. If you remove a part from the car then you need to save this into the database using a update operation in the car repository. Do you then have to find all the parts belonging to the car, then remove whatever part from the parts table? It means that I need to do find operations before updates?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on the design of your database.

Given cars and parts, I would have something like

```
table cars: car_id, name
table parts: part_id, description
table installed_parts: car_id, part_id
```

A `Cars` object would have a `List` of `Parts`, which are drawn from the information in `installed_parts`.

When `car.removePart(part)` is invoked, the `installed_part where car_id == Car.car_id and part_id = Part.part_id` is removed.